# LightDm does not have permission to read path (xubuntu Greeter Settings)

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, lightdm

I'm trying to set a custom background for the login screen through "LightDm GTK+ Greeter Settings:

whatever path I set I get an exclamation point next to the word **Background** with the error (on hover):

```
LightDm does not have permission to read path
```

these are the permissions for `/usr/share/backgrounds`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep  7 18:13 .
```

here are the permissions for `~/wallpapers`

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 david david 4096 Sep  7 11:59 /home/david/wallpapers
```

neither of these locations work..

I also tried `/usr/share/wallapers` and it didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

You should give permissions to the image (at least read permission to read the image in the path).

Just write in prompt:

```
sudo chmod ugo+rx /Path/Of/The/Picture.png
```

or

```
sudo chmod 555 /Path/Of/The/Picture.png
```

Or you can change the permissions recursively (to the directory and the internal files) with "-R" :

```
sudo chmod ugo+rx -R /Path/Of/The/Picture/Folder
```

or

```
sudo chmod 555 -R /Path/Of/The/Picture/Folder
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions may make the entire paths involved accessible to users you may not want to have that access. If you want to use an icon that is in your own Documents/Icons folder, for security reasons, copy your icon to a folder LightDM has access to.
e.g. /usr/share/icons on my system, found using:

sudo locate lightdm | grep .png

sudo cp /home/david/Documents/Icons/[your icon filespec] /usr/share/icons/.

If you want the filespec of the copy to be different, replace the . at the end with the desired filespec; and remember to put paths in quotes if they contain spaces.